# What is "#!' in a script file?

Tags: command-line, scripts, shebang

```
$cat shebang.sed 
#! /bin/sed -f
s/red/xxx/
s/BLUE/1234/

$./shebang.sed rgb
lower (#1): "xxx green blue"
UPPER (#2): "RED GREEN 1234"

$sed -f shebang.sed rgb
lower (#1): "xxx green blue"
UPPER (#2): "RED GREEN 1234"
```

I may guess what #! is doing. However, I don't say I know it. what is "#!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is called *shebang* and is used to tell the terminal which interpreter to use when executing the script. In your case, you use `sed`

Other examples would be:

```
#!/bin/bash            # -> uses bash
#!/usr/bin/perl        # -> uses perl
#!/usr/bin/env python  # -> uses python
```