# Unique project path in bat file

Tags: bash, automation, intellij, testing

I'm beginner in Linux environment. I moved my project with automated tests from Windows to Linux Ubuntu. In windows I have following bat file:

```
set projectPath=D:\git\testproject
cd %projectPath%
mvn clean test -Dxmlfile=dev.xml
pause
```

How can I create unique projectPath in Linux? Should I write a path variable?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 20.04. I don't use WSL in Windows. Here is my full path of my project in Ubuntu.
/home/admin/projects/testproject

Comment: Yes I have maven in ubuntu too.

Answer (score 1):

## Sample conversion from `bat` to `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Old bat lines are commented out
# set projectPath=D:\git\testproject
PROJECTPATH="home/admin/projects/testproject"
#cd %projectPath%
cd "$PROJECTPATH"
mvn clean test -Dxmlfile=dev.xml
#pause
read -p "Press the Enter key to continue" x
```

Save this code in a file. Give it a name, something like `mymvn` or `mymvn.sh`. Save the file in `~/bin`. See [Where should I put my bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998452/where-should-i-put-my-bash-scripts/998464#998464) for why.

Now you type the name of the bash file in the terminal to run these commands.

### Some background

The first line is called shebang. See [What is "#!' in a script file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994223/what-is-in-a-script-file) for more.

Linux is case sensitive. See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization). Also note, file and folder names are case sensitive too.

There is no `pause` command in bash. I used the `read` command. It waits for a keyboard input. This will keep the terminal open until you hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Hope this helps